# Twilio Queue management issue / best practice

Tags: twilio, call-flow

We are setting up a call center using Twilio.

At the end of the greetings and menus, our users are redirected to a queue waiting for the next available agent.

We would like the system to:
- Call automatically the next available agent. This is to prevent the agent from dialing the queue to know if users are waiting.
- Be able to change the order of the queue. Our users have different priorities.

How can we get this done? What are the best practices?

FYI: We are using PHP, TWIML and we DO NOT have our own IPBX (Not able to use SIP Protocol).

Thanks,
Dimitri

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

There are a few ways you could do this, but my suggestion would be to use the *action* attribute of the [Enqueue](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon) verb.

The [action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#attributes-action) attribute lets you tell Twilio about a URL that you want it to request when a caller leaves the Queue.  As part of this request, Twilio will pass you a parameter named [QueueSid](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/enqueue?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#attributes-action-parameters).  Using the QueueSid, you can make a request to [Queues](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#instance) endpoint in the Twilio API, see if the [current_size](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/queue?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=jan2014&utm_campaign=stackathon#instance-properties) of the Queue is greater than zero, and if it is initiate a call out to the next available agent.

Hope that helps.